# Forgot Password with asp.net identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, knockout.js, asp.net-identity, reset-password

In my MVC and web API projects I'm using ASP.NET Identity for the Login.

This is my Forgot Password function on the AccountController:

```cs
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("ForgotPassword")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> ForgotPassword(ForgotPasswordViewModel model) 
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid) 
    {
        var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Email);

        if (user == null || !(await UserManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user.Id))) 
            return Ok();

        try 
        {
            var code = await UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user.Id);
            
            var callbackUrl = new Uri(@ "http://MyProject/ResetPassword?userid=" + user.Id + "&code=" + code);

            string subject = "Reset Password";
            string body = "Please reset your password by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>";
            SendEmail(user.Email, callbackUrl, subject, body);
        } 
        catch (Exception ex) 
            throw new Exception(ex.ToString());

        return Ok();
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return BadRequest(ModelState);
}
```

I'm getting the confirmation email, I am successfully redirected to the Reset Password View but then I'm not sure how to proceed.

How do I reset a password with the following parameters: NewPssword, ConfirmPassword and Code?

I tried to call the `SetPassword` method but got a 401 error.

```js
self.resetPassword = function () {
    var data = {
        Email: self.loginUserName(),
        NewPassword: self.registerPassword(),
        ConfirmPassword: self.registerPassword2()
    }
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../API/Account/SetPassword',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        complete: showError
    });
}
```

And the setPassword function:

```cs
// POST api/Account/SetPassword
[Route("SetPassword")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> SetPassword(SetPasswordBindingModel model) 
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) 
        return BadRequest(ModelState);

    IdentityResult result = await UserManager.AddPasswordAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId(), model.NewPassword);

    if (!result.Succeeded) 
        return GetErrorResult(result);

    return Ok();
}
```

Currently the process is a s follow:

1. user clicks on "Forgot Password" link.
2. He is redirected to the Forgot Password View that has one field: Email.
3. The user provides his email address and submit the form.
4. the request is being sent to the Forgot Password function.
5. An email with a unique code is being sent to the client.

*Till here I wrote the code and got it to work but I'm not sure how to* implement the next steps:

6. The user is redirected the the Reset Password View that has 3 fields: Email, New Password and Confirm Password.
7. The user submits the form, a request is being sent to the SetPassword function (?) with the unique code and the user's password is being reset successfully.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like your SetPassword api should call

```
var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Email);
if (user != null)
{
    var result = await UserManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user.Id, model.Code, model.NewPassword);
    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
          //handle success
    }
}
//handle invalid
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm not sure what you mean, would you be able to explain?

Comment: you have to post relevant code to get an exact answer.. you posted the `ForgotPassword` action which you're saying works, but you did not post your `SetPassword` action which you say is returning an error.. it's hard to tell you exactly what's wrong by the 2 snippets you posted.

Comment: You are right, I edited my question, thank you very much for your help!

Comment: it seems like you should be using the ResetPassword method instead of SetPassword if you are resetting a password.. reason being, is that you're not actually logged in when you're resetting a password so `User.Identity.GetUserId()` will not be valid

Comment: But asp.net Identity doesn't provide by default a ResetPassword function. Do you have any idea where can I find a sample for it? Thank you!

Comment: it should be a method on `UserManager` at least in version 2.0  `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager.ResetPasswordAsync(TKey userId, string token, string newPassword)`

Comment: Yes, I found this function but I'm not sure how to write this ResetPassword  **Action** like ForgotPassword and SetPassword Actions etc... I'm not sure how to connect between the email confirmation that is being sent to the user and the `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager.ResetPasswordAsync(TKey userId, string token, string newPassword)` method.

Comment: there's an example in the default mvc template in vs2013 in the AccountController